# How do I fix it to output what I want to output?

Tags: java, for-loop, system.out

I recently started coding in Java, I just started a week ago. The previous post was deleted because I did not specify it enough, I am sorry for that. I've been having troubles with for, do and while statements, and how do I output the same results in the expected outputs that I have typed in? With the use of while or do or for only.

Current code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int row = 3;row <= 7;row++) {
            String spc = "  ";
            for(int column = 1; column <;= 3; column++) {
                System.out.print(column * row + spc);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Current outputs:

```
3  6  9  
4  8  12  
5  10  15  
6  12  18  
7  14  21
```

Expected outputs:

Set 1

```
3
4 6
5 8 11
6 10 14 18
7 12 17 22 27
```

---

Set 2

```
3 8 13 18 22
2 6 10 14 
1 4 7
0 2
-1
```

> I'm really having a hard time in solving this problem, any help will be very appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: You just need to reason out. the logic.  Your structure isn't far off.  The biggest problem I see is that your inner loop always loops 3 times.  But that determines the number of terms on a line.  So if you want 1 term on the first line, 2 on the next, etc., you can't have that loop always iterate 3 times.  The number of times must be based on the `row`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but could you explain it more? Please

Comment: I could just give an answer, but that doesn't help you learn.  Other than that, I don't know how to make it clearer.  You just have to reason it out at each level.  You have 3 terms on each line and that isn't what you want.  Why are there 3 terms on each line?  How do you change that?  Just reason it out.

Comment: I think you should approach easier first, this is tough for 1 week java developer

Comment: @NehaK, yeah, I think I should, I kinda wasted 2020 doing nothing, so I'm trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: I agree with NehaK - Now that you have a competent solution to your problem in @Rapt0r's answer, I suggest that you study that and understand every bit of why it gives you the desired result.  Once you understand it, think about how you might have come up with it yourself.  Programming is not so much about learning the syntax of a particular language, but more learning to break a problem down into pieces so that you can logically build up a solution piece by piece in your code.  I would suggest that you study the answer and ask more questions here if you need to.

Comment: @Steve - Ok, I'll take your advice to heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution to your problem.  I started with a row number, 1..5.  Then, I figured out from that value how many times I needed to perform the inner loop based on the row number.  Once I'm iterating the right number of times in the inner loop, then it's just a matter of making the math come out right to give the numbers you desire:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    for (int row = 1 ; row <= 5 ; row++) {
        String str = "";
        for (int term = 0 ; term < row ; term++) {
            str += ((row + 2) + row * term) + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int row = 5 ; row >= 1 ; row--) {
        String str = "";
        for (int term = 0 ; term < row ; term++) {
            str += ((row - 2) + row * term) + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
3 
4 6 
5 8 11 
6 10 14 18 
7 12 17 22 27 

3 8 13 18 23 
2 6 10 14 
1 4 7 
0 2 
-1
```

NOTE: I'm confident that the first line of the second set should end in `23`, not `22` as you show as the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will try to give you some hints instead of the answer.I would like to help you with one thing.If you see your set 1,there is a pattern.On your first line you have only 3 (basically printed one time your row value) on the second line you can see there are two outputs(second line,two outputs.third line three outputs)and it goes on.So I believe instead of doing your second for from 1 to 3 try to have a counter.Use that counter in your second for --> column < counter.Also each time try to print your row value before your second for statement and in your for statement I believe now that you have a counter it will be easier to find a better equation instead of column * row.Dont forget that you have to be increasing your counter!!I also made a flag variable that holds each time my row and add the counter on it but it's up to you how you want to do it.To do your set 2 its just the same logic but in reverse you'll be decreasing your for counter instead of increasing.If you have any questions even after you read this feel free to ask me :)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the code that provides answer for the set 1 requirement:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.print((i + 3) + (i + 1) * j + " ");  //Since someone else already answered, I am going to add it here too
            }
            System.out.println();  //To go to next line
        }
```

Explanation:

The outer for-loop determines the number of rows in the output (5 in this case). The inner for-loop determines the number of columns in that particular row in the output (the value is checked with i, since the first row contains one element, second row contains two elements and so on).

Use the same logic when you want to have 5 elements in the first row and decrease the number of elements with every iteration of i.

Hope this explanation helps you figure out the set 2's logic on your own.

Comment: What is the purpose of `elemCount`? Seems it's always `i+1`.

Comment: Yeah actually, it is always (i + 1). We can remove that too. Didn't notice that. Thanks.